# Fancybox append jQuery［ajax, $('body').on］ to body

Tags: jquery, caching, fancybox

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on("click",".showDetails",function(){
    $.fancybox({
        autoSize: false,
        width: '1000px',
        height: "100%",
        closeOnEscape: false,
        href: 'details.html',
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax : {
            type: 'post',
            cache:false
        }
    });     
});     
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="showDetails">Test</button>
</body>
```

details.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on("click",".test",function(){
        console.log("Test");         
    });
});

</script>
<button type="button" class="test">Console.log</button>
```

When I opened three times of the details through the Fancybox. Then, I click the .test button in the details.html of fancybox. The console will log "3" times of "Test"

What's that problem and how can I fix it? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you click `.test` every time or only the third one?

Comment: The number of console logs base on how many time I have opened fancybox in the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `cache : false` is not working for you , how about setting all AJAX call to cache : false by default. It will however be applied to all AJAX call ongoing in the current page.

In `$(document).ready`use ,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Which by default sets all AJAX `cache` to `false`

#### And here is the Documentation of  [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)